# Laravel 5.0 send array to controller with ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have this array in javascript that I want to send to my controller with an ajax call.

```
let order = sortable.toArray();
console.log(order);
```

Result of the log in my console:

```
(2) ["1", "0"]
```

My controller method:

```
public function reorder($newsletterId, Request $request)
{
    return response()->json([
        'status'    => 'success',
        'code'      => '200',
        'data'      => [
            'newsletter-id' => $newsletterId,
            'request'       => $request->all()
        ]
    ]);
}
```

This is my ajax call:

```
$.post(newsletterBlocks.getAttribute('data-url'), order, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
})
```

The result of the response log in my console:

```
{status: "success", code: "200", data: {…}}
code: "200"
data:
  newsletter-id: "56"
  request:
    undefined: ""
    __proto__: Object
  __proto__: Object
status: "success"
__proto__: Object
```

As you can see it says undefinied.

I've tried to JSON.stringify(order); but this results in an empty response

I've tried something like this but also results in an empty response:

```
var array = []
$.each(order, function(index, field) {
    arr.push('order'+index, field)
});
```

Comment: i don't think `$request->all()` is the best method here. I think you should individually take the output that you wanted and pass it on

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to take the output out individually, I am just trying to pass an array without keys or anything

Comment: can you see in console network tab what actually you get from laravel side?

Comment: I think you have made mistake here : Please try below for ajax post

$.post(newsletterBlocks.getAttribute('data-url'), {'order' : order}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
})